# How do you disable the Google Maps API?

Tags: wordpress, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to speed up my website and have found that Google Maps is the culprit. I have removed the maps but the scripts are still activating - https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?

Is there a way to disable them on my wordpress site?

Comment: They will only be there if something on your site is loading them.  Find that and remove it.

Comment: how about some of the code so we can help you figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

For more additional information, if you really wish not to use our API, you can always disable/enable it in the Developer Console. All you have to do is to follow the steps below:

1. Go to the GCP Console API Dashboard page.
2. GO TO THE API DASHBOARD PAGE
3. Click Select to choose the GCP project.
4. Next to the API you want to disable, click Disable.

or you can check Google Cloud's [**Enabling and Disabling Services**](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable).

Hope I was able to help you.

Comment: Thanks or the suggestion

Comment: hello dear @raton  
many thanks for the awesome thread.  I am having a heck of a time disabling google maps from the jobify-theme. I have followed the instructions from the documentation page on adding: 
but the site still fetches the google-data: in other words, the site still pulls the data from google - see the results:
 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412666/remove-google-maps-completely-from-the-wordpress-site
 
look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 1):

You should check if there is a plugin that calls it automatically and check if the plugin or theme has this option.
If the plugin or theme does not have this option you will need to manually search the code where it is being used and remove it.

Unfortunately in your case you will need to see the code of the themes or plugins on which the script is being called so that you can have a way to remove it.

Because each plugin / thema calls this in different ways and sometimes only manually to remove

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions

Comment: hello dear Kelvin hello dear DDraper, 
many thanks for the awesome thread.  I am having a heck of a time disabling google maps from the jobify-theme. I have followed the instructions from the documentation page on adding: 
but the site still fetches the google-data: in other words, the site still pulls the data from google - see the results:
 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/412666/remove-google-maps-completely-from-the-wordpress-site
 
look forward to hear from you

Answer (score 1):

To disable google maps api, you can simple delete Maps API Key.

1. Go to GCP Console and select your project
2. Go to APIs ^ Services > Credentials
3. In Api keys list, open actions dropdown for your Maps API Key
4. Select Delete API Key

when you delete all Maps API keys, maps service will be disabled for project.

Thats much faster than disabling all maps apis.